# Moving/Indenting Two Bytefields

Tags: bytefield

I created two bytefields with the package bytefield.

[image]

The code I used is the following:

```
\begin{bytefield}[endianness=little,bitwidth=0.077777\linewidth]{12}
\bitheader{0-11} \\
\bitbox{1}{82} & \bitbox{1}{70} &
\bitbox{1}{70} & \bitbox{1}{7} &
\bitbox{1}{23} & \bitbox{1}{34} &
\bitbox{1}{97} & \bitbox{1}{29} &
\bitbox{1}{16} & \bitbox{1}{44} &
\bitbox{1}{70} & \bitbox{1}{83}
\end{bytefield}

\begin{bytefield}[endianness=little,bitwidth=0.077777\linewidth]{6}
\bitbox{1}{82} & \bitbox{1}{70} &
\bitbox{1}{70} & \bitbox{1}{7} &
\bitbox{1}{23} & \bitbox{1}{34} & 
\end{bytefield}
\bigskip
```

The problem I have is that I would like to indent the lower bytefield by one field, that is, instead of aligning the lower bytefield with the fields 0-5 I would like to align it with 1-6. At the end of the bytefield I would like to add an arrow that points to the right side in order to indicate that the bytefield is moved from the left to the right. I guess the question is how to move two or more bytefields in relation to each other from left to right an vice versa.

P.S.:

Comment: The values at the second bytefield and the picture I uploaded do not match. That is because I changed the values in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Ti*k*Z for that?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,minimum width=1cm},
    row 1/.style={draw opacity=0,font=\tiny}% Can't figure out why draw=none doesn't work
] (m) {%
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11\\
    82 & 70 & 70 & 7 & 23 & 34 & 97 & 29 & 16 & 44 & 70 & 83\\
    & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60\\};
\draw[red,-stealth,thick] (m-3-7) -- ++ (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You also have many other tools to do so (tables, etc.) but IMHO Ti*k*Z is the easiest option (it is also helpful when you try to add any kind of arrows).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I didn't know that I can use TikZ for this since I am new to latex.

Comment: @complexi You are welcome :))

Answer (score 1):

You can make an empty bitbox with no borders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}

\begin{bytefield}[endianness=little,bitwidth=0.077777\linewidth]{12}
\bitheader{0-11} \\
\bitbox{1}{82} & \bitbox{1}{70} &
\bitbox{1}{70} & \bitbox{1}{7} &
\bitbox{1}{23} & \bitbox{1}{34} &
\bitbox{1}{97} & \bitbox{1}{29} &
\bitbox{1}{16} & \bitbox{1}{44} &
\bitbox{1}{70} & \bitbox{1}{83} \\
\bitbox[]{1}{} & \bitbox{1}{82} & \bitbox{1}{70} &
\bitbox{1}{70} & \bitbox{1}{7} &
\bitbox{1}{23} & \bitbox{1}{34} &
\bitbox[]{1}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[6em]{\rightarrowfill}}}
\end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```

[image]